# How do I stop Bitcoin Core from interrupting me with the "Loading wallets..." window?

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux

I run Linux. Debian 12. XFCE. I have installed Bitcoin Core. I think this same thing happens on Windows as well.

Basically, I have it start at boot. Then, after many minutes have passed and I have started typing something in some program, or begun working in other ways, I'm suddenly interrupted by a minimal GUI window saying "Loading wallets...", which pops up in front and steals focus.

This is insanely annoying as it happens long after Bitcoin Core has been started.

I have looked everywhere for a way to turn this pointless window off, or make it open in the background/minimized/not stealing focus. I've asked on IRC but was told that "it's open source so you can modify it yourself if it bothers you". Yeah... I'm not even going to comment on that one.

What can be done to stop this terrorizing window from popping up and stealing focus, interrupting my work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the interactive GUI application `bitcoin-qt` you should expect to see GUI alerts.

If instead you run the background daemon version `bitcoind`, and run it in daemon mode, I would expect the messages will be in the logfiles. You would use `bitcoin-cli` instead of the GUI if you need to interact with  Bitcoin core.